# JavaScript get request error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, xmlhttprequest

So I've been developing my application for a while now, and didn't encounter such an issue until recently this afternoon, when starting application after some changes in the javascript code I got an error while loading a request from server side like this:

[image: error image]

In the console I am writing readyState and status, and the first two values happen as soon as web page is loaded and other ones come after like 5-10s time out. This is the code that is supposed to be running.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(this.readyState);
    console.log(this.status);

    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      GetGoals(JSON.parse(this.response), goalsList);
    }
  };

  xhttp.open('get', '/api/mainmenu', true);
  xhttp.send();
});
```

I am starting my application on the file and running it on the chrome. While I googled i found some answers talking about certificate mismatch, but why would that happen only after some time? How could i solve this issue? I am developing on .NET Core asp.net 2 and vanilla js.

**EDIT:** It seems that only this get method fails, post method works fine which is even stranger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the issue was different from what I imagined. There was an issue with my SQL Servers. It seems that i might have turned off one or it got turned off somehow and it could not get the request to the database, which is strange indeed.